# How to get selected value in multicolumn listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a multicolumn listbox in my userform and I would like to get all the values of the elements which are in the selected row in the listbox.
Here is my userform:[image: UserForm with ListBox]

Just like in the photo, I want to select one line then I will click button `Associer` and I could get the information of this row. I can just get the first column which is `CAN20168301436` I want to get the information from the whole line.
 How can I do it? 
Here is my button clicked event:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   a = ListBoxResultatFind.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim strng As String
    Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

    With Me.ListBox1 '<--| refer to your listbox: change "ListBox1" with your actual listbox name
        For lRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1 '<--| loop through listbox rows
            If .selected(lRow) Then '<--| if current row selected
                For lCol = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1 '<--| loop through listbox columns
                    strng = strng & .List(lRow, lCol) & " | " '<--| build your output string
                Next lCol
                MsgBox "you selected" & vbCrLf & Left(strng, (Len(strng) - 1)) '<--| show output string (after removing its last character ("|"))
                Exit For '<-_| exit loop
            End If
        Next lRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

No need to loop the entire list - in order to get the selected item row you can use the `ListIndex` property. Then you can use the `List(Row, Column)` property to retreive the data, as in the examples by @DragonSamu and @user3598756:

```
'***** Verify that a row is selected first
If ListBoxResultatFind.ListIndex > -1 And ListBoxResultatFind.Selected(ListBoxResultatFind.ListIndex) Then
    '***** Use the data - in my example only columns 2 & 3 are used
    MsgBox ListBoxResultatFind.List(ListBoxResultatFind.ListIndex, 1) & ":" & ListBoxResultatFind.List(ListBoxResultatFind.ListIndex, 2)
End If
```

Comment: have you tested that? In my Excel VBA up to 2013 a multi-column `ListBox` `ListIndex` property would return `0` if no items selected, as if the first item would be. That's why I iterate through rows and check `Selected` property. An alternative would be double check for a `0` `ListIndex` like `If .ListIndex = 0 and .Selected(0) or .ListIndex >0 Then` but that would seem too unclear for a _second time around_ code review

Comment: @YiaoSun: as per my previous comment you may want to test this solution against a possible _no-selection_ scenario

Comment: @user3598756 No selection gives ListIndex = -1, that's why I test for `ListIndex > -1`. (I use Excel 2010 where it works like a charm!)

Comment: try selecting and deselecting a row: the `.ListIndex` value remains as the last selected (and then deselected) row was still selected, while `.Selected(.ListIndex)` (correctly) returns `False`

Comment: @user3598756 Btw, if the list is short maybe the cost of looping the whole list isn't that high, but since VBA is pretty slow anyway, any improvements you can make are welcome!

Comment: I surely agree with you

Answer (score 5):

With a single column you can retrieve the value as below:

```
Dim str as String
str = me.ListBox1.Value
```

With a multicolumn you can retrieve the value like this:

```
Dim strCol1 as String
Dim strCol2 as String
Dim strCol3 as String
strCol1 = ListBox1.List(0, 1)
strCol2 = ListBox1.List(0, 2)
strCol3 = ListBox1.List(0, 3)
```

or you can add all the data into 1 String:

```
Dim strColumns as String
strColumns = ListBox1.List(0, 1) + " " + ListBox1.List(0, 2) + " " + ListBox1.List(0, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, I tested ,it can just get CAN20168301436 but can't get all information, this is a multi-colonne listbox

Comment: It has 7 colonnes

Answer (score 1):

It's a 6column list box and the 3rd column would be the multiplier hence the "(x)". You may also rearrange the list to how you like it.

```
Private Function selList() As String
Dim i As Long

For i =LBound(lstListBox1.List) To UBound(lstListBox1.List)
    If lstListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        selList = selList & lstListBox1.List(i) & " " & lstListBox1.List(i, 1) _
        & "(x" & lstListBox1.List(i, 3) & ")" & " " & lstListBox1.List(i, 2) & " " & lstListBox1.List(i, 4) & ", "
    End If
Next i

If selList= "" Then
    selList= ""
Else
    selList= Left(selList, Len(selList) - 2)
End If

MsgBox selList
End Function
```