# Is it posssible to click on a listing after a dynamic search is run?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a dynamic search form that searches 8 fields. Depending on the field selection made by the user, that is what is shown in the form. When the user clicks on a particular listing, I would like the record related to that listing to be shown. I.e. McDonalds is selected & the record for the particular McDonalds is shown. The fields in the search are: Business Name, Address, City, State, zip, Phone Number, Major City, Employer Type. Major city is a field where jobs are in a particular area.

I have googled & have not found an answer to my question. Is what I am asking possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected value in multicolumn listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244444/how-to-get-selected-value-in-multicolumn-listbox)

Comment: As the link to a duplicate question shows , you can get the values with `ListIndex` for singleselect listbox and with a `Loop`+`Selected(i)` for multiselect listbox.

Comment: Are you working in MS Access?

Comment: Yes. I will look at Victor has posted & will respond back.

Comment: I did look at what @Victor suggested.  The requester stated that he was going to click on a button once a line was selected. I was wondering if it is possible to click on the actual line & call the record. I am trying to avoid a actual button.

Comment: @FrankM Listbox click/doubleclick produces an event. You can use that event coupled with the `ListIndex` to return a value to use it for something else.

Comment: @victor. You are brilliant. I went back & really looked at what you suggested, & what the suggested code said. I think that once I customize it to my database. It should do the trick.

Comment: @ Victor.I am getting a syntax error on this line ` Set ctl = frm!Business Name`.  Apparently I am missing something. I have goggled & they all show what you pointed me to.  Is **Set ctl **the column name or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the following code on after click. It opens a form that shows all the data for that particular record. A friend of mine assisted me.

```
Private Sub SearchResults_Click()
Dim strCriteria As String
'"ID" is the list box's BoundColumn, as would usually be the case, a hidden numeric EmployerID value.
'SearchResults is the list box's name.
 strCriteria = "ID = " & Me.SearchResults
'EMPLOYER_DATA_ENTRY_FORM is the name of the form that opens.
 DoCmd.OpenForm " EMPLOYER_DATA_ENTRY_FORM", WhereCondition:=strCriteria
 End Sub
```