# How to Transfer ListBox selection to excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with a single selection ListBox (*lstKitResult*) that is populated with data from the sheet *Kit_database*. The user can search using a keyword and only filtered data is displayed. After the user makes a selection I would like to transfer this information to cells B3 and C3 in the sheet *Update_kit*. The ListBox shows 5 columns but I would like to transfer over values from only 2 of these columns (first two columns). This is the code I am currently using:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdateKit_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Update_kit")

    Dim nextAvailableRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To lstKitResult.ListCount - 1
        nextAvailableRow = ws.range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.range("B" & nextAvailableRow) = lstKitResult.Column(0, i)
        ws.range("C" & nextAvailableRow) = lstKitResult.Column(1, i)
    Next i

    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

It transfers over all filtered results and all columns from the ListBox to *Update_kit* rather than just the selection and its associated data. Also, the info is dumped into the empty row rather than cells B3 and C3 as I mentioned.

I'm still fairly new to VBA and cannot figure out where the issue is. Can someone advise how to fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected value in multicolumn listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244444/how-to-get-selected-value-in-multicolumn-listbox)

Comment: @JvdV thank you for letting me know but I believe that post doesn't consider populating an excel sheet with the selection but rather showing a message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming this is a userform?

You can do it thus. Loop through each item until you find the selected one and then transfer the relevant columns (zero-based).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Update_kit")

Dim i As Long, nextAvailableRow As Long

nextAvailableRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 0 To Me.lstKitResult.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lstKitResult.Selected(i) Then
        ws.Range("B" & nextAvailableRow) = Me.lstKitResult.List(i, 0) 'column 1
        ws.Range("C" & nextAvailableRow) = Me.lstKitResult.List(i, 1) 'column 2
        Exit For 'no need to carry on searching
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Other than having to switch column 1 and 2 this worked perfectly! Thank you for your help.