# delete a line or item selected on listbox of userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a userform where I can enter some information, but I want also to give the user the possibility to delete the data that he entered by selecting it from listbox and then click on delete and they need to put a password. Unfortunately, I tried this code but it's doesn't work.

```
Private Sub delete_Click()
Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To Range("A65656").End(xlUp).Row
    If lstdiplay.Selected(i) Then
      Rows(i + 1).Selected
      Rows(i).Select
      Selection.delete
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

When I select for example XOXO like the picture, and click on DELETE, i want to delete the entire information about XOXO, does mean delete XOXO and SA and his number phone etc.....and yes I have the same data on worksheet and After deleting data cells I want to remain blank

[image]

Comment: "It doesnt work"? What error did you get? What happens when you step through it? Where are you asking the user for a password?

Comment: @brax I have the error 424 and the ligne lstdiplay.Selected(i) highlighted

Comment: Do you really have data in all 65656 rows? What is the value of `i` when it breaks? how many items are in the listbox? 65656?

Comment: @braX no I do not have 65656 entries, I do not have an exact number from the start because I fill in a sheet so I must take into account a maximum number, this is why I left 65656; but when I entered only 4 entries, and I tried the code, it gives me the error; normally my table starts from line 3, so even if I put i=3 , nothing has changed

Comment: The `.Selected` property tells you if an item is selected or not, or is used to make it selected or unselected. You are not using it like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244444/how-to-get-selected-value-in-multicolumn-listbox `Rows(i + 1).Selected` makes no sense.

Comment: ok, so how can delete from the listbox, ie by selecting the entry from the listbox and then delete it ?

Comment: Do you want to delete the row only from the listbox, or from the worksheet, too?

Comment: @FaneDuru from the listbox and the worksheet

Comment: When you save the "cells to remain blank" this doesn't mean the row will be deleted... So, you need to remove the line from the listbox and clear the specific row? If yes, next time when you will load the data in the listbox you will have a blank row, if you do not use some conditions. The most rapid method to load it is to create a Variant variable which to be load with the range you need and then use the '.list' listbox property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub delete_Click()
    Const listStart As Long = 3 'Your listbox keeps the rows starting with row 3
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'better use your worksheet name here...
    If Not Me.lstdiplay.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Me.lstdiplay.RemoveItem Me.lstdiplay.ListIndex
        sh.Rows(Me.lstdiplay.ListIndex + listStart).Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "You must have a listbox selected row!", vbInformation, "No row selected"
    End If        
End Sub
```

It removes the selected listbox row and deletes the equivalent sheet row. If the listbox has been loaded starting from row 3 inclusive. Otherwise, you should adapt the `listStart ' constant value...

It also warns in case of selection missing.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it's works, but I want to undestand well your code, why you put Me.lstdiplay.ListIndex = -1 , why is equal -1 ? because I knwo listindex start from 0

Comment: Not really... If you do not have anything selected `Me.lstdiplay.ListIndex` will return -1. The code "says" `Not Me.lstdisplay.ListIndex = -1`. If nothing selected, you receive a message to warn you about that, instead of an error message...

Comment: @axel: If it works as needed, an answer vote up will not kill anybody... :-)