# Need Help: Run-Time Error 214724809 (80070057). Cannot Find the Specified Object

Tags: vba, listbox, runtime-error, userform

I am VERY new with VBA and the code.

I have a Userform, and there is a search box where the user can enter a Shop Order Number and if the number is in the data table, it will show in a listbox, located underneath the search box. This listbox also keeps the last several searches.

The search works great. However, when I click on one of the Shop Order Numbers in the listbox, I get the error message.

> Cannot Find the Specified Object

lstSearch = name of the listbox

txtShopOrdNum = textbox name of the Shop Order Numbers

I have 130 columns in the data table (Master)

cmbAddNew = Command Button

cmbUpdateSave = Command Button

```
Private Sub lstSearch_Click()
For i = 0 To 130
  Me("txt" & Format(i, "ShopOrdNum")) = lstSearch.Column(i)
Next
cmbAddNew.Enabled = False
cmbUpdateSave.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate the help. This is for work and I can't get past this error.

Comment: `ShopOrdNum` is not a valid format string. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Reading listbox column values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39245253/478884   To refer to a control by name use `Me.Controls(controlNameHere)`

Comment: When you click on a Shop Order Number in the listbox, it should populate all of the fields, from the same row as the Shop Order Number you click on.

Comment: What are you expecting this to return? `Format(i, "ShopOrdNum")` - If `i=0` then it returns `00opOr300u12` - Do you have a control named `txt00opOr300u12` ?

Comment: I wish I could show the file. I got this code from someone. I expect when I click on a Shop Order Number, ex: ASO-12345, that the form fields will populate with data from the same row as ASO-12345. 
Here's the original code: 
```Private Sub LB_00_Click()
For i = 0 To 64
    Me("T_" & Format(i, "00")) = LB_00.Column(i)
Next
'T_06.value = Replace(T_06.value, ",", ".")
Cmb_00.Enabled = False
Cmb_01.Enabled = True
End Sub```

Comment: It looks like you might mean `Me("txt" & Format(i, "00"))`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: The guy that gave me the code, changed all of my textbox names. He named them all T_00, T_01,T_02, etc. I had to change them back to names I could understand, e.g., txtShopOrdNum, txtPONum, txtPOAmt, etc. I am so new at VBA. I assumed he used "T_" and "00" because that is the textbox name for txtShopOrdNum.

Comment: No, the `00` is a format string. Do not change that.

Comment: Oh geez, that's confusing to a newbee. I changed the code, but now get a runtime error 424: Object required. Private Sub lstSearch_Click()
For i = 0 To 130
  Me("txt" & Format(i, "00")) = lstSearch.Column(i)
Next
cmbAddNew.Enabled = False
cmbUpdateSave.Enabled = True
End Sub

Comment: By the way braX, thank you for the link. That information is helpful.

Comment: So now, `Format(i, "00")` will return `00` - Do you have a control called `txt00`? If `i=1` then it will be `txt01`

Comment: I ran the debug on the runtime 424 and it's pointing to an entirely different line of code.  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
lstSearch.List = [MASTER].Value
frmMaster.Show
End Sub

Comment: No, I do not have a control called txt00.

Comment: "He" had a textbox control named: T_00, I renamed it: txtShopOrdNum. So, I changed the code line from Me("T_" & Format(i, "00")) to Me("txt" & Format(i, "ShopOrdNum"). This is the first column of the data table.

Comment: If you don't have a textbox for each column in the grid named correctly already on your form, then this code is not going to do anything except error. It looks to me like you are missing a LOT from wherever you got your code.

Comment: I do have a textbox for every column. It's hard to grasp this when you can't see the file. Other functions work fine, so I know the textbox names are good. Is there a way I can show you the file?

Comment: To use this approach all of your textboxes must follow a systematic naming convention like "txt000", "txt001" ... "txt130" otherwise there's no way for you to get the control name from `i`   Are you using Access, Excel, or ?

Comment: I am using Excel. I was afraid this is why this was happening. I'm so new at VBA that naming the textboxes like: txtShopOrdNum, txtPONum, etc. helped me understand the code a little better. However, it may not be a good best practice. I appreciate your guidance Tim.